# Position divs equally, overflow them when there are too many

Tags: html, css

I have `<div class="wrapper">` and all divs inside it are positioned next to each other equally. But when I have too many of them, they are too close to each other. So when there are more then 4 divs, I want to make scrollbar appear. Every div will take at least 25% of the parent div.

I've tried to add `min-width: 25%` to divs inside wrapper, but it didn't work.

How can I do it in CSS?

```css
.wrapper {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

.wrapper div {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div style="position: absolute; background-color: #dedede; bottom: 5%; left: 5%; width: 90%">
  <p>text...</p>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div>Aaa</div>
    <div>Aaa</div>
    <div>Aaa</div>
    <div>Aaa</div>
    <div>Aaa</div>
    <div>Aaa</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use flex and set the flex-basis to 25% on the children and `overflow: auto` on the parent.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  overflow: auto;
}

.wrapper div {
  flex: 0 0 25%;
}
```

```html
<div style="position: absolute; background-color: #dedede; bottom: 5%; left: 5%; width: 90%">
        <p>text...</p>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div>
                Aaa
            </div>
            <div>
                Aaa
            </div>
            <div>
                Aaa
            </div>
            <div>
                Aaa
            </div>
            <div>
                Aaa
            </div>
            <div>
                Aaa
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```